# No known class method for selector 'URLAssetWithURL'

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, nsurl, avurlasset

I have an iOS app which uses a lot of different audio files recorded in the app and saved. I have imported AVFoundation framework, however I still get the error:

> No known class method for selector 'URLAssetWithURL'

Here is my code:

```
AVAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:audioFiles[indexPath.row]]];
waveformView.asset = asset;
```

Inside the audioFiles array is a local URL like the following:

> file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6B35F9EA-1896-4989-91AF-06850B74B2E9/Documents/record_sound_1.aif

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the class reference at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVURLAsset_Class/index.html

the class method takes two parameters, the URL and some options. Change to:

```
AVAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:audioFiles[indexPath.row]] options:nil];
waveformView.asset = asset;
```

I would expect XCode's autocompletion and highlighting make it obvious that you were using a method that didn't exist...

Comment: Great thank you very much sir. Actually Xcode didn't come up with any popup .... But anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: It occurs to me that you'll get better checking from the IDE if you type your variable more specifically. Unless there's a reason not to, declare `asset` as `AVURLAsset *asset` rather than `AVAsset *asset` and see what XCode tells you then.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the second argument in that method call. [URLAssetWithURL:options:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVURLAsset_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/AVURLAsset/URLAssetWithURL:options:) is declared like:

```
+ (AVURLAsset *)URLAssetWithURL:(NSURL *)URL options:(NSDictionary *)options
```

In your call you are missing the `options` parameter.